# Detecting the presence of a specific smartphone

Tags: usb, rfid

I would like you to give me some clues about a projet I have: I want to make sure that my little brother's smartphone stays in a shelf overnight and during school hours in order to monitor the time he spends with it.

In order to fulfill my needs, I thought of using an Arduino to detect that the smartphone stays in proximity at certain hours.

Since this is my first Arduino project, I'm not quite sure what I could do, and what is possible to do.

Hence I've got a lot of questions:

- Can I easily detect that a specific smartphone is in range?
- Can I use the smartphone's NFC (RFID) to do so?
- What kind of output could I possibly get from an Arduino? I would like to make statistics, so it must be stored somewhere, and I know Arduino doesn't have a lot of memory.
- Is it possible to write on a USB key?
- Which Arduino is best suited for my needs Should I consider buying an Arduino with Ethernet in order to send emails?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd suggest looking into the apps that exist, that will let you schedule phone/app usages. Something like e.g. http://ourpact.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

> Can I easily detect that a specific smartphone is in proximity ?

It can be done, yes. How "easily" depends on how much money and expertise you have to throw at it.

> Can I use the smartphone's NFC (RFID) to do so ?

It is possible to use that, yes - if you add the right hardware and software to the Arduino.

> How long can an Arduino run on battery using a 9V battery from the market ?

A couple of hours if you're lucky. They are useless batteries.

> What kind of output could I possibly get from an Arduino ? I would like to make statistics, so it must be stored somewhere, and I know Arduino has not a lot of memory.

Whatever you want. Again, it's SMOP / SMOH.

> Is it possible to write on an USB key ?

Sure, if you get the right hardware for that.

> Which Arduino is best suited for my needs ? Should I consider buying an Arduino with Ethernet in order so send email ?

The Arduino that provides the facilities your project requires - and that depends on how you are going to decide on how to do it. Remember: the Arduino is just the "brain" of the operation. You need to decide what "organs" the brain needs to control and in what way.

There's a million and one ways of achieving what you want. You could even do it 100% in the phone in software (there's probably an app for that...) without need of an Arduino...